# TSQL - If Exists Update Else Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a data file with data in below format.

--removed the data and query

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the order of operations - first update lookup tables, then do your import merge. You can remove your temp table, the inserts, and updates for those lookup tables. You just need a merge statement to bring in the new and/or updated rows.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Let me try that.